# How to use progressbar in an async webclient call from a viewmodel

Tags: c#, mvvm, progress-bar, windows-phone-7.1

I am trying to use performance progressbar in a WP7 project but I have trouble with the async webclient call. My code is as follows:

**Update**

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
         ...................

        this.Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(MainPage_Loaded);}

    private void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!App.ViewModel.IsDataLoaded)
        {
            App.ViewModel.LoadData();
        }
    }
```

And the ViewModel where I implement the LoadData function

```
    private bool _showProgressBar = false;
    public bool ShowProgressBar
    {
        get { return _showProgressBar; }
        set
        {
            if (_showProgressBar != value)
            {
                _showProgressBar = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("ShowProgressBar");
            }
        }
    public void LoadData()
    {
        try
        {
            string defaulturl = "http://....";
            WebClient client = new WebClient();
            Uri uri = new Uri(defaulturl);
            client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);
            ShowProgressBar = true;
            client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

        this.IsDataLoaded = true;

    }

    void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //fetch the data
           ShowProgressBar = false;
        }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }

    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(String propertyName)
    {.....
    }
```

MainPage Xaml

```
    <toolkit:PerformanceProgressBar Margin="0,-12,0,0" x:Name="performanceProgressBar" IsIndeterminate="true" Visibility="{Binding ShowProgressBar, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

My problem is that because the WebClient is an async method when it is executed, the LoadData has already been executed and I can't figure out where to place the performanceProgressBar.Visibility

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What exactly are you looking to do with "performanceProgressBar.Visibility"? Are you trying to set it to visible when the load starts and hidden when completed?

Comment: Maybe I'm over simplifying your issue, but why aren't you just setting visibility to Visible right before you call "client.DownloadStringAsync" and then at the end of the async completed handler, just set the visibility to Hidden or Collapsed. The important part is that since the "completed handler" comes in on another thread, you'll have to marshal the call onto the GUI thread as mentioned below.

Comment: Because the DownloadStringAsync() is in the ViewModel from where I don't have access to the progressbar, which is in the View, in order to change its state. Am I missing something here?

Comment: check out my answer below, I think I have a better idea of what you want. The way you were writing your question made it sound like you were doing this in the code-behind, so you had access to the progressbar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After you explained more in your comments, I understand more. Sounds like you want to bind a boolean property to the visibility of your progress bar. You'll need a boolean-to-visbility converter (google it, it's easy to find).

Then you can do something like this:

```
private bool _showProgressBar = false;
public bool ShowProgressBar
{
    get { _return _showProgressBar; }
    set 
    { 
        _return _showProgressBar;
        OnPropertyChanged("ShowProgressBar");
    }
}

public void LoadData()
{
    try
    {
        string defaulturl = "http://....";
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        Uri uri = new Uri(defaulturl);
        client.DownloadStringCompleted += new DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadStringCompleted);

        ShowProgressBar = true;

        client.DownloadStringAsync(uri);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

    this.IsDataLoaded = true;

}

void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //fetch the data
        ShowProgressBar = false;
    }

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

On the View:

```
<MyProgressBar Visibility={Binding Path=ShowProgressBar, Converter={StaticResource MyBoolToVisibleConverter}>
```

Apparently, MSFT offers a converter for you already...this is news to me: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.booleantovisibilityconverter.aspx

Comment: I don't know what I am doing wrong but unfortunately I can't figure out the problem. I have used BooleanToVisibilityConverter from Coding4fun toolkit but with no luck :(

Comment: Well what problem are you having still? What errors are you getting if any?

Comment: The problem is that the progressbar is not hiding. I have updated the code if you would like to see the changes.

Comment: The ShowProgressBar value changes as expected. But I think that something goes wrong with the binding and the converter.

Comment: Do you have any other properties on your view model that are binding to the view that you've verified are displaying and updating on the view? If they're not updating, does your ViewModel implement INotifyPropertyChanged? This is is necessary to notify the view that it should update a binding value.

Comment: OK I found the problem. I forgot to set the MainPage DataContext to the ViewModel. Now the binding works and the progress bar disappears as expected. I have one more question if you don't mind. The UI is freezing for a moment until the data is loaded and the property change event fired. How can I prevent that freeze?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get back on the UI thread -- the `Dispatcher` can help you out, and a common snippet I use (in my ViewModelBase is:

```
    protected delegate void OnUIThreadDelegate();
    /// <summary>
    /// Allows the specified deelgate to be performed on the UI thread.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="onUIThreadDelegate">The delegate to be executed on the UI thread.</param>
    protected void OnUIThread(OnUIThreadDelegate onUIThreadDelegate)
    {
        if (Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
        {
            onUIThreadDelegate();
        }
        else
        {
            Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(onUIThreadDelegate);
        }
    }
```

This can then be used simply with:

```
void client_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        //fetch the data

        this.OnUIThread(() =>
        {
            performanceProgressBar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed; // This code will be performed on the UI thread -- in your case, you can update your progress bar etc.
        });

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you please be more specific on how to use that snippet in my code? I have to implement that into the viewmodel inside the client_DownloadStringCompleted() ?

Comment: Taken a stab, but you may need to tweak/flesh out/do a bit of effort to get it to work with the rest of your solution.

Comment: Hmm I see. But, as I mentioned above, how can I have access to the progressbar control from the viewmodel since I have declared it to the MainPage xaml? I am definitely missing something here..

Comment: Well, you could raise an event on your viewmodel (on the UI thread), and have your view react to that.