# Windows Phone 8 ProgressBar incorrectly displaying with ListBox

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I have a situation with my app whereby the ProgressBar displays correctly when OnNavigatedTo is executed.  Then during the process of searching for and collating the data resuested, the ProgressBar hangs/freezes.  Finally, when all data has been collected and displayed correctly in the list, the ProgressBar collapses correctly.

My XAML looks like this:

```
<ProgressBar
    x:Name="progressbar"
    IsIndeterminate="True"
    Minimum="0"
    Maximum="100"
    Value="0"
    Width="400"
    Height="30"
    Foreground="#FF117B0F"
/>
```

My C# looks like this:

```
List<GameLive> gameLive;

public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    gameLive = new List<GameLive>();
    ProgressBar progressbar = new ProgressBar();
}

protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    base.OnNavigatedTo(e);
    string htmlPageLive = "";
    bool isError = false;

    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

    try
    {
        htmlPageLive = await client.GetStringAsync("webpage");
    }

    catch (Exception)
    {
        isError = true;
    }

    if (isError)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Unable to retrieve data");
        return;
    }

    HtmlDocument htmlDocumentLive = new HtmlDocument();
    htmlDocumentLive.LoadHtml(htmlPageLive);

    foreach (var div in htmlDocumentLive.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("..nav.."))
    {
        bool isErrorTwo = false;
        GameLive newGame = new GameLive();
        try
        {
            newGame.Title = removed;
            newGame.Summary = removed;

            gameLive.Add(newGame);
        }

        catch (Exception)
        {
            isErrorTwo = true;
        }

        if (isErrorTwo)
        {
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Temp.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            return;
        }
    }
        lstGameLive.ItemsSource = gameLive;
        progressbar.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        progressbar.IsIndeterminate = false;
}
```

I've tried multiple solutions but have run out of options.  Can somebody please point me in the right direction here?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It's a problem related to the async methods as they freeze the UI (as I think) till the execution finishes.

You might want to look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24827009/progress-info-using-httpclient) and also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926978/how-to-pause-an-application-without-freezing-the-ui)

For a much more cleaner code, try binding the progress bar visibility like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11057969/how-to-use-progressbar-in-an-async-webclient-call-from-a-viewmodel) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17262320/how-do-i-program-my-progress-bar-in-combination-with-asynchronous-calls)